# Problem with Sample App in LightSwitch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-lightswitch

I downloaded the sample LightSwitch app (Online Ordering) and i got an error that i couldnt figure out \ solve.

> Error 1   The "SqlInstanceName" parameter is not supported by the "BuildSchema" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\LightSwitch\v1.0\Microsoft.LightSwitch.targets    160 23  OnlineOrdering

and

> Error 2   The "BuildSchema" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\LightSwitch\v1.0\Microsoft.LightSwitch.targets    157 10  OnlineOrdering

the error is in the following section

```
<!--The Development Database is built in the same location - Bin\Data - for all configurations.-->
    <BuildSchema Inputs="@(LightSwitchModel)"
                 ProjectPath="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
                 OutputDirectory="Bin\Data"
                 SqlInstanceName="$(SqlInstanceName)"
                 ExternalDataSources="@(ServerExternalDataSources)"/>
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote that sample. I know it works because I have installed it on a number of machines.

However, LightSwitch was just released today and I have not tested it on the released version of LightSwitch.

What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it turned out that I had a problem with the Lighswitch extension. The problem is solved now

But i am trying a sample app, when i try to save i get this error:

The underlying provider failed on Open.
Inner exception message:
Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed.